# Copying/taking tools from one ubuntu distro to another

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I would like to know how can I copy tools from one Linux distribution (such as cyborg hawk 1.1 based on Ubuntu ) to another Linux distribution such as Back-box (also based on Ubuntu). The reason why i would like to do this, is because cyborg hawk has a lot more tools than back-box. I know i could rather boot up the Cyborbg OS, but i don't need all of the tools. So am looking for a way to get selective tools and add them to the Back-Box menu. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Generally, tools that work on one Ubuntu-based distro will work on another, particularly if they're for the same underlying version of Ubuntu.  The farther apart the underlying versions, the more likely you may run into problems.  It's similar even within the same distro.

Answer (score 0):

each tool is connected with a ppa. both dists are based on ubuntu, so it should be no problem to add the tool into your new dist. if you do not find an according ppa, then it's not supported in the target dist.  alternatively goto to the dev page of the tool. most tools can be downloaded by source. after downloading expand the archive and compile the tool. copy/paste won't work.